# Google cannot locate my GitHub repositories - Google Site Verification fails

Tags: git, github, verification

I created a `GitHub` site last September using a `Windows 10` laptop.  Since then I have created five repositories.  `Google` has never been able to locate any of them.  A week ago I created a `GitHub Page` for the main repo but `Google` has not been able to locate it yet either.  `Microsoft Edge`/`Bing` can locate the repository.

I provided links to the main repo and its `GitHub Page` in this post.  Then harrymc suggested in a comment that I change the name of the repo.  I have done that.

The original links (which might not work anymore) were:

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/Tutorial_for_Running_a_Large_Number_of_R_files_using_Amazon_Web_Services

https://icterusgalbula.github.io/Tutorial_for_Running_a_Large_Number_of_R_files_using_Amazon_Web_Services

Today I recreated the repo and `GitHub Page` after harrymc's comment to:

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/RAWStutorial

https://icterusgalbula.github.io/RAWStutorial/

and renamed the original repo and `GitHub Page` to:

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/Tutorial-for-Running-a-Large-Number-of-R-files-using-Amazon-Web-Services

https://icterusgalbula.github.io/Tutorial-for-Running-a-Large-Number-of-R-files-using-Amazon-Web-Services/

For months I tried adding a `Google Site Verification` file
downloaded from `Google Search Console` and pushed to the main repo of interest.

https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome

Mostly I tried using the original url for the main branch of the `GitHub` tutorial repo in `Google Search Console` (under `URL prefix`).  The original link, which might not work anymore after following harrymc's suggestion today, was:

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/Tutorial_for_Running_a_Large_Number_of_R_files_using_Amazon_Web_Services/tree/main

The new URL's as of this morning are:

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/Tutorial-for-Running-a-Large-Number-of-R-files-using-Amazon-Web-Services/tree/main

and

https://github.com/IcterusGalbula/RAWStutorial/tree/main

`Google Search Console` returned this error message when I clicked the `Verify` button after uploading the verification file to the main branch of my original `GitHub` tutorial repo.  I have not tried this process after creating the new repo with the shorter name and renaming the original repo this morning:

> Verification method:
> **HTML file**
>
> Failure reason:
> **Your verification file has the wrong content. Are you using the verification file that you downloaded here?**
>
> Please fix your implementation and reverify, or use another verification method.

The content of the `Google Site Verification` file is:

```
 google-site-verification: google229f9162496d16ab.html
```

I have done everything I can think of to resolve this issue including working through ~15 hours of video in multiple `Git` and `Github` courses on `Udemy`, watching `YouTube` videos, searching the internet and adding a link to my `GitHub` repository multiple places on the internet including my `Stack Exchange` profile.

Answers to this `StackOverflow` post seem to be to try using `Google Search Console` and the question has been closed.  That approach is not working for me as described above:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199705/github-repository-not-listing-in-google-search

I also have looked at a similar post on `GitHub Community`:

https://github.community/t/cant-see-my-github-page-on-google/10947

and asked for help myself on that forum.

Thank you for any suggestions and assistance 1.) enabling `Google` to find and list my `GitHub` repos and/or my `GitHub Page` in search results and 2.) verifying my `GitHub` repository.

Comment: Your project is also successfully found by DuckDuckGo and Yahoo. I would guess that this is a search engine crawler problem, perhaps to do with your title being one *very* long word. Try replacing the underscores with space, and let the engines time to crawl it before testing.

Comment: You could probably verify ownership of your repo files by using the raw url: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/reponame/main/` and see if it will crawl based on that. (you may need to generate+upload a new verification file)

Comment: @MarkMiller: Have you tried my above advice?

Comment: @harrymc  Yes I did.  Google still cannot locate my GitHub site or GitHub page.  However, I have managed to get Google to verify my GitHub Page and I think I am on the last step of having Google index my GitHub Page.  My GitHub Page links to my GitHub repository.  So, maybe after the GitHub Page is indexed everything will be fine.  But I might not know for another week.

Comment: From your answer, I see that you have tried to accelerate the crawl over your page. If it now works, the difference might be my advice...

Comment: So I added an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have made partial progress.  `Google` has verified my `GitHub Page` and is in the process of indexing that page.  I have not been able to verify my `GitHub` repository.  However, my `GitHub Page` links to my `GitHub` repository.  So, after `Google` finishes indexing my `GitHub Page` maybe `Google` will be able to list both the page and the repository in search results.  I will not know for maybe another week.

Below are the steps I used to verify my `GitHub Page` based on this post by `klues`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199705/github-repository-not-listing-in-google-search

1. Go to `Google Search Console`

https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome

I made sure I was using the same `Gmail` account to log into both `GitHub` and `Google Search Console`.

2. Paste the `URL` of your `GitHub Page` into the `URL Prefix` box.  For example, I used:

https://icterusgalbula.github.io/RAWStutorial/

This `GitHub Page` is referred to as a `property`.

3. Click `Continue`
4. Scroll down to the `HTML tag` verification method section and copy the meta tag displayed by clicking the word `COPY`
5. Paste that text into your `index.html` file in your `GitHub` repository.  Bracket that text between `<head>` and `</head>`.  The actual `html` code was not displayed here when I tried.  My `index.html` file is in the `gh-pages` branch of my `GitHub` repository.
6. Commit the changes made in your `index.html` file (i.e., update your repository).
7. Click the word `VERIFY` on the `Google Search Console` screen
8. Hopefully `Google Search Console` will verify your `GitHub Page` site.  My site was verified.
9. Click `GO TO PROPERTY`
10. You must wait approximately 48 hours after which a different `Google Search Console` screen will appear with a search bar at the top.
11. Paste the `URL` of the `GitHub Page` into that search bar at the top of the new `Google Search Console` screen.  However, this time use a slightly different version of the `URL` than was used in Step 2.  This time add `index.html` to the end of the `URL`:

https://icterusgalbula.github.io/RAWStutorial/index.html

12. Click `Enter`
13. Request Indexing
14. Wait for Google to index the `GitHub Page`.  I do not know how long this will take but I guess it could take anywhere from a couple of days to a couple of weeks.  Here is a screenshot of the current state of my `Google Search Console` display while I wait for `Google` to index my `GitHub Page`.  Note the checkmark next to `Indexing requested`:

[image]

I will update this post after the indexing of the `GitHub Page` is completed (or fails).

**EDIT: August 19, 2021**

`Google` still is not able to locate my `GitHub` page.  The following screenshot shows that `Google Search Console` `Coverage` is still `processing data` ~ one month after creating this post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your project is also successfully found by DuckDuckGo and Yahoo.
I would guess that this is a search engine crawler problem,
perhaps to do with your title being one very long word.

My advice was to replace the underscores with space,
which the poster did, and then let the search engines time to crawl it.